# How to layer a moving average on line chart with vega-lite?

Tags: moving-average, vega-lite

With [vega-lite](https://vega.github.io), it is clear that you can aggregate data using standard methods like the mean, sum, etc. But what about a moving average?

Let's say I have some simple time series data, so the x-value is a date and the y-value is a value of some sort. Now let's say I want to render a line chart with that data, and then layer on top of it a moving average plot. Is there a standard way to do this using vega-lite?

I've tried to look for some sort of solution in the docs, but haven't been able to find any reference. It seems as though this is a common use-case and so I'm wondering if it exists?

If it doesn't, I guess I would just generate the moving average values myself.

Answer (score 3):

Vega-Lite includes a [window transform](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/window.html) that is designed for precisely this. You might be able to adapt the [Cumulative Moving Average](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/window.html#cumulative-running-average) example from the documentation to the dataset you have in mind.